# Customize Search Box CSS in Bootstrap 3 and placement of elements in Navigation Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a newbie to Bootstrap and I am having a hard time aligning elements in the way I want.

I want my navigation bar to look like this:
[image]
 While now, it is something like this:
[image]

What should I do so that the logo shifts a few pixels on the side? I tried over-riding the Bootstrap CSS by using margin-left in style.css:

[image]

but that displaces the logo in small and medium resolutions. Like this:

[image]

I want the logo to stick on the corner when the display is medium and small and be displaced like shown in the image only when the resolution is full scale. I am told that I must do that using Media Queries. Any other better alternatives using Bootstrap 3 classes or even a implementation in Media Queries will do. I have hosted the site [here](https://ae9b21d2de5fe39e92f83abce83fb380f30ab420.googledrive.com/host/0B0byAC8kZZPhQTN1MG5KZVZoWk0/) and the HTML/CSS and Bootstrap files [here](https://drive.google.com/#folders/0B0byAC8kZZPhQTN1MG5KZVZoWk0).

I have another minor issue with the search box. 
Right now, its like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:
[image]

What change should I make to the CSS code that my search box looks the way I desire?
I am having a hard time adding customization to Bootstrapped CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the search input you could try something like...

```
      <style>
        .search-input{
         background-color: rgb(228, 102, 48); 
         border: 2px solid #fff; 
         box-shadow: none; 
         border-radius: 50px;
         color: #fff;
        }

        .search-input ::-webkit-input-placeholder, .search-input :-moz-placeholder, .search-input ::-moz-placeholder, .search-input :-ms-input-placeholder { {
           color: #fff;
           font-weight: bold;
        }

/** rotation if needed **/
       .glyphicon-rotate-180 {
         transform: scaleX(-1);
     -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
        }

        .search-icon {
        position:relative; 
        color: #fff; 
        right: 30px; 
        top: 2px;
        }

        </style>
```

I'd probably put the css in your main css sheet.

This is what the markup would look like...

```
<input type="text" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" />
<a class="search-icon" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search glyphicon-rotate-180"></i></a>
```

**EDIT

Replacing style with

```
  .search-icon {
            position:relative; 
            color: #fff; 
            right: 30px; 
            top: 29px;
            }

<div class="pull-left" style="position: relative;">
<input id="srch-term" class="form-control search-input pull-left" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term">
<a class="search-icon" type="submit">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search glyphicon-rotate-180"></i>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The CSS works like a charm except for one hindrance, The search icon is outside the input box. Here's how [link] https://ae9b21d2de5fe39e92f83abce83fb380f30ab420.googledrive.com/host/0B0byAC8kZZPhQTN1MG5KZVZoWk0/ [link] it looks.

Any suggestions how I could bring it inside the input box? 
And thanks a lot for writing the CSS down. I was hoping you could direct me to some resources that next time, I dont have to ask and instead I be able to write the CSS myself. Could you tell me how you learnt it through? :)

Comment: I believe there was a container around that original markup you had, which you removed I think if you put that div that was around it originally it should work again. As far as resources to learn...I really learned more by doing. For example, if I see something cool in CSS I'd inspect the element in firebug and view how the styling was and try to implement it later myself. Thats really about it for me honestly. Also looking at how bootstrap does things is also good way to learn.

Comment: And thats a perfect FIX! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example of a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #logo {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #logo {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
    #logo {
        margin-left: 250px;
    }
}
```

Just add it to your CSS file, change the id by the one of your logo and it should work as you expect. Resolutions smaller than 992px will apply margin-left: 0px;

About the input. To override bootstrap's rules you could use !important or be more specific about the element:

```
.navbar .nav li .input-group input { ... }
```

This should make look the input you have very similar to the one you want:

```
.input-group {
    border: 2px solid white !important;
    border-radius: 20px !important;
}

.input-group input {
    background: orange !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 20px !important;
}

.input-group .input-group-addon {
    background: orange !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 20px !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'll just ask another small help. I followed your method and its perfectly working for all dimensions except for resolution between 960px to 1010px. The navigation bar doubles in size between 960px to 1010px.
Please see these images. Beside, in red, I have mentioned the resolution too.
http://s2.postimg.org/jyl5xigzt/Screenshot_13.png
http://s2.postimg.org/41me0soll/Screenshot_14.png
http://s2.postimg.org/ghj3ujhxl/Screenshot_15.png
The website address is same.
Can you think what the problem is? I know 960px is a Bootstrap breakpoint, but what at 1010px? Why is the website behaving such?

Comment: The website is here: https://ae9b21d2de5fe39e92f83abce83fb380f30ab420.googledrive.com/host/0B0byAC8kZZPhQTN1MG5KZVZoWk0/
The HTML and CSS is here: https://drive.google.com/#folders/0B0byAC8kZZPhQTN1MG5KZVZoWk0

Comment: You don't need to add !important to override elements. Actually as far as I have been taught if you are using !important willy-nilly you probably arn't doing it "right". In multiple projects of mine i've been able to override the bootstrap styling by using the fact that styles are added in a "cascading" fashion

Comment: Hi, your webpage seems to be working correctly so i think you found the problem. About what @ScottMitchell said, he is correct, using !important is considered a bad practice so you should try to avoid using it.